# Removing duplicated rows in the most efficient way

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I an wondering what is the best way to remove duplicate rows, but keeping other data within the row.
For instance, let's say I have two rows that has the same ID, and I want to remove either one and keep just 1 copy of that row based on that field(s).

Online searches show that the answer is probably using `| summarize arg_max(TimeField,*) by ID`. However, since KQL is a columnar database, this operation is "heavy" by design, and will increase the processing time, probably significantly.
I was wondering if there is no way around it, or there is a more efficient way?

Thank you!

I tried to remove entire duplicate rows using `arg_max` but given the nature of the function, it is making the query to timeout.

Answer (score 0):

1. 

> "It is making the query to timeout."

The default timeout is 4 minutes.
You can increase it up to an hour.

2.

> "Since KQL is a columnar database, this operation is "heavy" by design."

This might be a "heavy" operation due to the cardinality of the IDs.
You might need to use *summarize* with [hint.strategy=shuffle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator#arguments) instead of the default algorithm.
It has nothing to do with columnar.